# JavaFX program won't run with FontAwesome-FX web icons

Tags: java, intellij-idea, fonts, javafx-2, glyphicons

I have been given the following output when including an FXML file with 3 icons of type MaterialDesignIconView

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=64397:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/reshaunp/toolsuite/out/production/toolsuite:/Users/reshaunp/Downloads/fontawesomefx-8.9.jar ToolSuite.Main
objc[59702]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1018fc4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1019c34e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Sep 24, 2017 10:24:10 AM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.111 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.31
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$49/1972439101.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser.<init>()V from class de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon
    at de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon.<clinit>(GlyphIcon.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:438)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1001)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:742)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2701)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2521)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3208)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
    at ToolSuite.Main.start(Main.java:23)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$52/29516901.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/42768293.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/311946107.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1834188994.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Exception running application ToolSuite.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I cannot pin point why I am getting this problem. I have downloaded the library the usual way using Intellij as well.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem should be **to use FontAwesome 8.4-SNAPSHOT**.

As described in the following link https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/issues/13/illegalaccesserror-on-fontawesomeicon version 8.9 has this bug.

This is the correct dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
  <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
  <version>8.4-snapshot</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: THIS DOES NOT HELP

Comment: Well at least I do not know how to use that code you provided. I downloaded the FontAwesome version 8.4

Comment: @compute, That's a maven dependency, when working with Java projects it is best to use a tool like Maven for project management instead of downloading a jar file and adding to your project manually, that's why I provided it. On the other hand, is your problem solved with version 8.4?

Comment: No it isn't. Can you provide pictures